# Get only first row per subject in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was wondering if there is an easy way to get only the first row of each grouped object (subject id for example) in a dataframe. Doing this:

```
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # do stuff
```

gives us each one of the rows, but I am interested in doing something like this:

```
    groups = df.groupby('Subject id')
    for index, row in groups.iterrows():
    # give me the first row of each group
       continue
```

Is there a pythonic way to do the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Direct solution - without `.groupby()` - by `.drop_duplicates()`

what you want is to keep only the rows with first occurrencies in a specific column:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='Subject id', keep='first')
```

## General solution

Using the `.apply(func)` in Pandas:

```
df.groupby('Subject id').apply(lambda df: df.iloc[0, :])
```

It applies a function (mostly on the fly generated with `lambda`) to every data frame in the list of data frames returned by `df.groupby()` and aggregates the result to a single final data frame.

However, the solution by @AkshayNevrekar is really nice with `.first()`. And like he did there, you could also attach here - a `.reset_index()` at the end.

Let's say this is the more general solution - where you could also take any nth row ... - however, this works only if all sub-dataframes have at least n rows.
Otherwise, use:

```
n = 3
col = 'Subject id'
res_df = pd.DataFrame()
for name, df in df.groupby(col):
    if n < (df.shape[0]):
        res_df = res_df.append(df.reset_index().iloc[n, :])
```

Or as a function:

```
def group_by_select_nth_row(df, col, n):
    res_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for name, df in df.groupby(col):
        if n < df.shape[0]:
            res_df = res_df.append(df.reset_index().iloc[n, :])
    return res_df
```

Quite confusing is that `df.append()` in contrast to `list.append()` only returns the appended value but leaves the original `df` unchanged.
Therefore you should always reassign it if you want an 'in place' appending, like one is used from `list.append()`.

Comment: AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'applymap' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Comment: If we just use the apply function and somehow check that the size of the returned group's rows is greater or equal to the queried nth row, then I guess it will work

Comment: @laza - yes, it was `.apply()`

Comment: the thing is that if I want to generalize your solution for the nth row, as in df.groupby('Subject id').apply(lambda df: df.iloc[n, :] if df.shape[0] > n-1 else?).mean() then what should I put in the else statement of the lamda? Some objects might not have the necessary amount of rows to be queried

Comment: yes ... I don't see a solution for the case that the data frames are too short ... I was trying too just now ... It works only if every data frame has at least n rows. Otherwise, one has to loop with `for` over each data frame and collect the 1-row data frames ...

Comment: I was thinking of returning NaN in that case but lambda needs something that can be indexed...grrr :(

Comment: one has to construct a for loop - and maybe return last nth-rows - and remove later on by `.remove_duplicates`, because every dataframe has to return a data frame row - because of the implicit `aggregate` at the end.

Comment: can you please post your idea so i can test it ?

Comment: Now I have it - oh man - it was really hard - because of one-off problems

Comment: to the actual quesetion: my `.drop_duplicates()` solution is nicer, isn't it? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `first()` to get first row of each group.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'subject_id': [1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4], 'val':[20,32,12,34,45,43,23,10]})

# print(df.groupby('subject_id').first().reset_index())
print(df.groupby('subject_id', as_index=False).first())
```

Output:

```
    subject_id  val
0   1          20
1   2          12
2   3          43
3   4          23
```

Comment: Then why not `print(df.groupby('subject_id', as_index=False).first())`